# Sending list of objects from LWC works with wrappers but fails with list of maps

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, map, wrapper-class

I have a LWC that sends the following list to apex

```
0:
Agent_Mobile_number: "999999999999"
Call_Date: "2021-05-08"
Call_Remarks: "LOL"
__proto__: Object
1:
Agent_Mobile_number: "99999999999"
Call_Date: "2021-05-09"
Call_Remarks: "LMAO"
```

in LWC :

```
insertcallRecords({
                    csvRows: this.getRowsConvertedToDicts(this.rows),
                    columnIndices: this.headerColumnNumbers
                })
                    .then(result => {
                        console.log('Result', result);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                    });
```

In the Apex I tried to capture these as a map and ran into an "internal server error"

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void insertCalls(List<Map<String,Object>> csvRows,Map<String,Integer> columnIndices){
    try {
        System.debug('csvRows : ' + csvRows);
        System.debug('columnIndices :'+columnIndices);
        // System.debug('rows : ' + rows);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if I create a wrapper in my apex and keep that as a parameter to the function, the code works fine. Converting the wrapper into a  list of map<string,string> works fine as well

```
class callWrapper {
       @AuraEnabled public String agent_mobile_number {public get; public set;}
       @AuraEnabled public String call_remarks {public get; public set;}
       @AuraEnabled public String Call_Date {public get; public set;}
    }
@AuraEnabled
    public static void insertCalls(List<callWrapper> csvRows,Map<String,Integer> columnIndices){
        try {
            System.debug('csvRows : ' + csvRows); // Works 
            List<Map<String,String>> rowMap = (List<Map<String,String>>)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(csvRows), List<Map<String,String>>.class);
            System.debug('rowMap :' + rowMap);  // Works
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

What could be causing the List<Map<String,String>> as the parameter to fail ?

Comment: Can you try iterating over the 'csvRows' list items, then over the map keys and values to pinpoint where it is failing? It might be a JS object prototype/function conversion issue since the wrapper maps the strings correctly

Comment: If I have the list csvRows as a list of objects, I am successfully able to iterate over it. After trying the problem again, converting csvRows to List<Map<String,String>> worked !

Answer (score 1):

Your `@AuraEnabled` method should have been `List<Map<Integer,Object>>`

You had it as `List<Map<String,Object>>`

Here is my working code passing the below object literal to the server - it works with no probs.

```
objArray = [{
    0:{Agent_Mobile_number: "999999999999",
       Call_Date: "2021-05-08",
       Call_Remarks: "LOL"},
    1:{Agent_Mobile_number: "999999999999",
       Call_Date: "2021-05-09",
       Call_Remarks: "HUH"}
    }
  ];

  connectedCallback(){
    this.invokeInsertCalls();
  }

  invokeInsertCalls() {
    insertCalls({data:this.ObjArray})
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('Result', result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      })
  }
```

Here is the `Apex` method:

```
  @AuraEnabled
  public static String insertCalls(List<Map<Integer,Object> > csvRows){
    try {
      System.debug('csvRows : ' + csvRows);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
    return 'Looks Good';
  }
```

Comment: I tried moving to Map of integer and object and ran into an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQKxf.png) "Value provided is invalid for action parameter 'csvRows' of type 'LIST". I've logged the list of objects sent to the function and it appears like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgGxG.png)

Comment: Well, this code compile and runs with no issues. Can you put that output in the question? Perhaps JSON.stringify() it for best output results.

Comment: There is really no need to have the `List` at all - it's only got one element.